# Objective-C Find the most commonly used words in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am trying to write a method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)wordFrequencyFromString:(NSString *)string {}
```

where the dictionary returned will have the words and how often they were used in the string provided.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to iterate through words in a string to analyze each one - only each character which seems like a bit more work than necessary. Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind that this probably is a bit more work than you were guessing if you want it to be anything but incredibly simple. Do hyphens mark the end of words? Emdashes? What about the Japanese は?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSString has `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:` method which allows to enumerate all words directly, letting standard api to do all necessary stuff to define word boundaries etc:

```
[s enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])
                      options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                   usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                       NSLog(@"%@", substring);
                   }];
```

In the enumeration block you can use either NSDictionary with words as keys and NSNumber as their counts, or use [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that provides required functionality for counts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to split the string and `NSCountedSet` will count the words for you.

1) Split the string into words using a combination of the punctuation, whitespace and new line character sets:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *separators = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
[separators formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSArray *words = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];
```

2) Count the occurrences of the words (if you want to disregard capitalization, you can do `NSString *myString = [originalString lowercaseString];` before splitting the string into components):

```
NSCountedSet *frequencies = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:words];
NSUInteger aWordCount = [frequencies countForObject:@"word"]);
```

If you are willing to change your method signature, you can just return the counted set.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into an array of words using `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]` first. (Use `[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]` as the argument to split on all non-letter characters.)

Comment: Then, just use the words (elements) in the array as the key and an NSNumber as the value for your dictionary. This simplifies your job of comparing strings—NSDictionary will then do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used following approach for getting most common word from NSString.

```
-(void)countMostFrequentWordInSpeech:(NSString*)speechString
{
    NSString     *string     = speechString;
    NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet new];
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                               options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){

                                    [countedSet addObject:substring];
                            }];
    // NSLog(@"%@", countedSet);
    //Sort CountedSet & get most  frequent common word at 0th index of resultant array
    NSMutableArray *dictArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [countedSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [dictArray addObject:@{@"object": obj,
                               @"count": @([countedSet countForObject:obj])}];
    }];

    NSArray *sortedArrayOfWord= [dictArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO]]];
    if (sortedArrayOfWord.count>0)
    {
        self.mostFrequentWordLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frequent Word: %@", [[sortedArrayOfWord[0] valueForKey:@"object"] capitalizedString]];
    }
}
```

"speechString" is my string from which I have to get most frequent/common words. Object at 0th index of array "sortedArrayOfWord" would be most common word.